# Rewriting jQuery files with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I am looking to start using angularjs within my application. I have been able to write some controllers and get them utilized from the front-end. What i am trying to do now is refactor some existing .JS files that us jQuery. For example:

**Original message.js file**

```
define([ 'jquery' ], function($) {
'use strict';

return function(router) {
    router('*', function(ctx, next) {
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined');

            $('.message').on('click', function() {

                $(".message").show();               

            });     

        next();
    });
};
});
```

**Attempted new message.js file**

```
define([ 'angular' ], function($) {
'use strict';

return function(router) {
    router('testpage.html', function(ctx, next) {
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined');

            $('.message').on('click', function() {

                $(".message").show();
                alert('its working)';

            });     

        next();
    });
};
});
```

However when i click on .message now, nothing appears to happen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `angular.element()` instead of `$()` since angular works with jQlite which is accessible via `angular.element()`.

Furthermore the access via class is not possible in jQlite.
The doc says:
`angular.element(element) // HTML string or DOMElement to be wrapped into jQuery.`